# How to run cuke4duke through jruby in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I want to run cucumber in my java project directly through jruby without having to use Ant or Maven. I have installed cuke4duke through jruby and have it up and running. I can run the feature files but I have problem in getting my step definition recognized by cucumber. Although I have the step definition folder, implementations are shown as pending to me.
What can I do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet, feel free to [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-7247).